# FInd a span's text which itself is dynamically generated

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV which is dynamically created using jQuery.

```
<div id="post-1">
<ul class="action-bar"> 
<li>
    <span class="likepostval" id="likecount-113">35</span></span>
    <span class="likepost">like</span>
</li>  
<li><a class="muted">6 days</a></li>  
</ul>
</div>
```

There are several such div with IDs post-2, post-3 and so on... I'm using the following jQuery script to fetch `.likepostval`'s id and text.

```
$(document).on('click','.likepost',function(){
var id = $(this).closest('.likepostval').attr('id');
var text = $(this).closest('.likepostval').text();
});
```

For the above script the console says 'Undefined'. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: What does `$(this).closest('.likepostval')` return? Is it `undefined`?

Comment: yes it says undefined, for text it shows empty space

Comment: Use `$(this).closest('li').find('.likepostval');`, because `.likepostval` is not a parent of `.likepost`, so `.close()` won't find it!

Comment: perfect... works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.closest returns the nearest *ancestor* element matching the selector. What you want is a *sibling*:

```
var id = $(this).siblings('.likepostval').attr('id')
```

...Etc.

Also note: you have an extra closing span in there.